# SQLCipher with asymmetric encryption

Tags: encryption-asymmetric, sqlcipher

Is it possible to encrypt data with SQLCipher using a private key? The intention is to store some sensitive data encrypted on the device that can be decrypted for debugging purposes. Unfortunately the SQLCipher documentation just mentions sqlite3_key() for symmetric encryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCipher only performs symmetric authenticated encryption, encrypting each page within the database.  You might consider moving your sensitive information to a SQLCipher database, while managing your non-sensitive information in a separate plain-text database.  SQLCipher can operate on plain-text databases as long as no key is provided.

Comment: That's not the answer I hoped for, but thanks anyway